# LocationManager android

Tags: java, android, gps, location

If i do:

```
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 1000, 0, locationListener);
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1000, 0, locationListener);
```

android get me the position with best accuracy between gps and network?

Answer (score 0):

No.  It will provide you with updates from both.

As long as you can actually get a satellite signal, GPS will always be more accurate.  But it costs more battery.  If accuracy is all you care about, all you need is GPS-  unless you need to be usable indoors.  Then requesting both may be appropriate, but you'll have to decide which ones to use (generally by expiring a GPS location and using a network if you haven't gotten a GPS update in a while).